# How does the synthesis of [18]annulene proceed stepwise?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis

Finding good literature on the synthesis of [18]annulene is challenging, as most sources are well old and quite archaic, so I was hoping some explanation in regard to the mechanism of synthesis.

My biggest question is in regard to the formation trimeric intermediate formed by Glaser coupling of  1,5-hexadiyne. It is not clear to me why this reaction seems to be "templated" towards forming a ring, instead of forming a linear structure formed by the terminal carbon's. In any case, I could not find any reason why this reaction could not be used for forming larger or smaller rings than being 18 carbons long, but I must be missing something.

Here is a good basic synthesis template: [OrganoSynth](https://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p0068)

Comment: For readers: See [annulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulene) group of unsaturated hydrocarbons.

Comment: Have you references for this?  A reaction scheme would be useful

Comment: https://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=cv6p0068

Comment: Should have added one, like Mithoron did. In any case, you can see how they are from the 60’s (The references)

Comment: Did you see the yield of [18]-annulene in the Org. Syn. preparation? 0.54%! Perhaps there is considerable polymerization.

Comment: Perhaps there is, perhaps the synthesis is complicated. As I said, the literature is sparse and relatively old. or at least from what I could find.